# Multiplying Determinants by a constant!

Tags: matrices, determinant

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/12HCj.jpg)

Hello! As I know when we multiply a determinant by a constant we must multiply the answer also by that constant but in these two examples in one of them I had to and in the other not. Can someone explain this to me?

---

$
\begin{vmatrix}
 -5 &-1 &-1 &-1 \\
 -2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix} \overset{(1)}=
\begin{vmatrix}
 -5 &-1 &-1 &-1 \\
 -2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 -\frac25 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
 -\frac{27}5 &-1 &-1 & 0 \\
 -2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 -\frac25 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
  -\frac{27}5 &-1 &-1 \\
 -2 & 3 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
 27 & 5 & 5 \\
 -2 & 3 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 324+40+30 = 394
$

(1): Last row multiplied by $\frac15$

---

$
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
  3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
  4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  0 &-1 &-2 &-7 \\
  0 &-2 &-8 &-10\\
  0 &-7 &-10&-13 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
 -1 &-2 &-7 \\
 -2 &-8 &-10\\
 -7 &-10&-13 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 7 \\
 -2 &-8 &-10\\
 -7 &-10&-13 \\
\end{vmatrix} =
-\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 7 \\
  0 &-4 & 4 \\
  0 & 4 & 36 \\
\end{vmatrix} = -(-144-16) =  160
$

Comment: The first determinant is -394.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Some MSE users tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post. Notice that you can also add explanations of the steps - like it was done in the very first step of the computation of the first determinant.

Comment: I'm new here so I had problems while writing the problem so instead I just took a picture of it. Nothing's changed at the problem. See at the first determinant when we divide the last row by 1/5 shouldn't we then multiply the answer by 5?

Comment: And thanks for the editing!